# How to query a table where data will be use as column name/field name

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Say I have this table:

```
Day     AMFrom      AMTo        PMfrom      PMTo
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Monday      09:00       Null        Null        06:00
Tuesday     09:00       Null        Null        06:00
Wednesday   09:00       Null        Null        06:00
Thursday    09:00       Null        Null        06:00
Friday      09:00       Null        Null        06:00
Saturday    08:00       Null        Null        05:00
Friday      08:00       Null        Null        06:00
```

How can I query this table to have this kind of output:

```
MondayAMFrom        MondayAMTo  MondayPMFrom        MondayPMTo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
09:00               NULL        Null                06:00
```

The output also includes `TuesdayAMFrom, TuesdayPMto,.......... SundayPMTo.`

Comment: Thank you for editing vignesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified the schema for brevity but it can be applied to your schema as well:

```
create table tbl(day varchar(20), amfrom int, amto int);
insert into tbl values ('Monday', 9, null);
insert into tbl values ('Tuesday', 10, 11);

select 
  MondayAmFrom,
  MondayAmTo,
  TuesdayAmFrom,
  TuesdayAmTo
from 
(
  select
    amfrom as MondayAmFrom,
    amto as MondayAmTo
  from tbl where day = 'Monday'
) as mon
,  
(
    select 
      amfrom as TuesdayAmFrom,
      amto as TuesdayAmTo
    from tbl where day = 'Tuesday'
 ) as tue;
```

This is the output:

```
MONDAYAMFROM MONDAYAMTO TUESDAYAMFROM TUESDAYAMTO
9            (null)     10            11
```

We create subqueries selecting each day. Then we join them in the main table. The days of the week need to be known which is the case in your example. There are only 7 of them.

`Select case when then` will not work here because it will create 7 rows and it will be difficult to group them. The problem with grouping is that your schema supports nulls.

[SQLFiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/591d2/10)

Comment: I like both you (Evpo) and Vignesh's approach but based from my question including other days such as tuesday, wednesday, etc I prefer your approach Evpo. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DECLARE @sql AS varchar(max)
DECLARE @Day AS varchar(max)
SET  @Day = 'Monday'

SET @sql = 'SELECT AMFrom As ' + @Day + 'AMFrom,
                   AMTo As ' + @Day + 'AMTo,
                   PMFrom As '+ @Day + 'PMFrom,
                   PMTo As ' + @Day + 'PMTo
            FROM Table1
 WHERE Day = ''' + @Day+ ''''

 Exec(@sql)
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7986/24)**

Comment: I'm thinking of using pivot. But this interest me. I will definitely try this. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that it will only work for Monday but in the question Tuesday will also be needed in the same table

Comment: actually Borat I don't have any idea how to do this the time that I posted it. I try searching the net and I found pivot. Now that I see Vinesh's approach I can now have a strong approach I believe.

Comment: @Borat Sagdiev How can it be fine if it only shows one day of the week?

Comment: @evpo - I'll take that back. I thought he wanted only monday per his question. Yes, Vignesh answer will not help here. I wrongly assumed that his approach can be repeated for the other days.